# Printing special characters

Tags: python, encoding, ascii

My string has some special characters I've tried using

```
s. encode('ascii', 'ignore')    
s.encode('utf8')
unicode(s).encode('utf8')
str(s).encode('utf-8')
```

But all of them fail. I keep getting an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there any other way to fix this

Comment: The `encode` should work, except you're not doing anything with the result.  It's not an in-place modifier.

Comment: It depends on how *special* is you character. This is an important thing that you forgot to add in the question. Could you add what it is `s` (and example), and which encoding is it. Note: for most of us, most of Unicode code points are not so special, and from the question I do not understand if you are meaning escape sequences, various selectors, or Hangul (which are treated differently, in Unicode), or what.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the text using `unicode-escape`, following is an example to get non-ascii characters by encoding with `utf-8` first and then decoding with `unicode-escape`.

```
>>> a = "Alive (M\\u00f8me Vs Midnight To Monaco)"
>>> b = a.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
>>> b
    'Alive (Møme Vs Midnight To Monaco)
```